DialogFlow having trouble importing coffee shop agen
I am having trouble with importing the prebuild agent. It gets stuck on the preparing agent and left it loading screen. Left it loading for over and hour.
I was thinking it would take a few minutes to load.
How long does it take?
I do not know what to try to get it to work.
I appreciate any one that can help.
